# laravel Validator::make() method throws error when i am using slash in name attribute ( ErrorException: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'h' )

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

Here is a snippet of Controller method & Html form it throws an error when I am using a slash in an attribute, everything working fine if I rename to anything else. Rest of thing working fine.

Controller

public function store(Request $request){

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
    'images/project_pics.*' => 'image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:1024', // images/project_pics.* not working 
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    return false;
}

return true;
```

}

Html Form

```
<form action="{{ route('image.upload.post') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="images/project_pics[]">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Maybe just don't use `name="images/project_pics[]"`; the `/` is likely causing some issues with Laravel's internal logic to determine input to check via `images/project_pics.*` Something like `image_project_pics[]` and `image_project_picks.* => '...'` should work.

Comment: actually works fine with image_project_pics[].but I want to do with using slash

Comment: Ok, but you can't :P Laravel uses `/` internally as a separator, so `image_project_pics/*` would be the same as `image_project_pics.*`.

Comment: You are right. I can't.

Comment: Don't mean to be blunt. You _might_ be able to, but it would require a lot of circumvention of Laravel conventions, which goes against the point of using Laravel in the first place. Don't make coding hard for yourself; do what works with the technology you're using.

Comment: actually I was trying to make dynamic directories with name attributes. but fine I changed internal logic and it works fine.
here is git repo if you are interested to see  https://github.com/dipenparmar12/laravel_testing/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/ImageController.php